# HTML checkbox without label tick not displaying

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a checkbox without a label tag with CSS.

```
input[type='checkbox']:after{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: #fff;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Tick is not appearing after clicking the checkbox. What is the missing thing here?
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30aLdkb1/)

Comment: The original checkbox is behind your :after, and therefor not visible.

Comment: to your checked:after css rule add property: background: none;  It is because :after has 15px by height and width overlay.

Comment: @Arturas After adding  background: none; tick mark is visible but original checkbox is appearing, I'm trying to have a big tick relative to box

Comment: checkout my answer @pupil

Answer (score 1):

For check inside checkbox you can put `content: '✔';` inside `input[type='checkbox']:checked:after`

Here is simple solution

```css
input[type='checkbox']:after {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
    content: '✔';
    text-align: center;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

here my jsfiddle you can checkout [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mzkegpw1/2/)

---

## Different Way

for that you need to add Fontawesome CDN to use icon to your project

```
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

after that just add in ur css under `input[type='checkbox']:checked:after{}`

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
    /* content: '✔'; */
    content: '\f00c';
    text-align: center;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';   
}
```

also you can find here fontawesome [Cheatsheet for Code](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)

```css
input[type='checkbox']:after {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(192,192,192);
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -4px;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
    /* content: '✔'; */
    content: '\f00c';
    text-align: center;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';   
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

checkout fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zwfLqo6d/)

Comment: How do I have a same styled tick like original checkbox tick

Comment: you want original check on it..?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, with html entity for a tick symbol

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    content: '\2713';
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. But how to add a similar tick relative to original checkbox tick but in a bigger size

Comment: You can increase tick symbol with font-size property.